# Can I edit EditText?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to change the edit text.Suppose I have a edit text with values :-

```
aa
bb
cc
```

Now I want to change "bb" with "zz" and modified edit text like

```
aa
zz
cc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Method [EditText.getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) return [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) object, so you may use Editable methods (replace/delete/insert).

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple :)

```
myTextEdit.setText("zz");
```

Comment: It will remove existing text of EditText and set "zz".

Comment: AVD: yes. The question has been changed since I answered it.

Answer (score -1):

Its very easy, first of all get the String from EditText using following syntax.

```
String str = myEditText.getString();
```

Now Replace it using following syntax.

```
str = str.replace ( "bb","zz" );

myEditText.setText ( str );
```

Comment: It wont replace the Text of EditText.

Comment: Agree, but now it will, I have updated my code. thanks for pointing out my mistake